# How to get the string value that matches in the 'Description'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a 'molecules' dataframe and a 'Description' dataframe (having shape (18000,1) and (75-000,1) respectively). There can be one or multiple molecule names present in the 'Description' dataframe. Now I am able to get whichever indices in 'Description' dataframe have molecule names from the 'molecules' dataframe but how can I get the value(string) that matches with the 'Description' column and store it in a new column in the 'Description' dataframe. Below is the code I have used to for comparison:

```
zipped = zip(part2['Item Description'], list1['molecules'])
part2['Matched'] = np.array(set(a.split()) & b for a, b in zipped).astype(bool)
```

I want to value 'b' for every 'Description' and store it in order .Thanks in advance.

Here is the sample dataframes that I have:
DF1:

```
molecules
benzene
sodium 
vitamin A
```

DF2:

```
Item Description
100 mg combination of benzene and sodium.
Will need to increase vitamin A dosage.
```

The output dataframe I want:

```
Item Description                            Matched_molecule
100 mg combination of benzene and sodium.   benzene,sodium
Will need to increase vitamin A dosage.     vitamin A
```

Comment: for easy understanding, please post sample dataframes and the desired output.

Comment: Got it. I hope now its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok for the sake of simplicity, I just wrote down both of your input dataframes in code. Note that I defined the molecules table as a Series and the item description as DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

ser1 = pd.Series(['benzene', 'sodium', 'vitamin A'], name='molecules')

df2 = pd.DataFrame(['100 mg combination of benzene and sodium.',
                    'Will need to increase vitamin A dosage.'], 
                    columns=['Item Description'])
```

Now I simply apply a lambda function on the column 'Item Description' of df2 that checks for every molecule in ser1 if it is in the item description and if, adds it to a list (via list comprehension). The join-command than makes a string out of the list with comma as seperator.

```
df2['Matched_molecule'] = df2['Item Description'].apply(
        lambda desc: ','.join([mol for mol in ser1 if mol in desc]))
```

Output is as suggested.